# Azure SaaS Marketplace SendGrid error while trying to configure after account creation

Tags: azure, sendgrid

After creating a Sendgrid account frim the SaaS marketplace based on the steps here (https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021#create-a-twilio-sendgrid-account) we are unable to proceed to "Configure account now".

We are redirected to (https://api.azure.integrations.sendgrid.net/v1/authenticated) with a "Signup Error. A Twilio SendGrid subscription already exists for this tenant." message.

[SendGrid Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z16ly.png)

We are 100% sure we dont have another sendgrid account in the same Azure subscription. Not sure what sendgrid exactly means by the above error.

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this resolved we have the same problem>?